# How to block form submission when the enter key or return key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I use JQuery, I don't think I need to put code in this post, the question is pretty basic.

But I would like to block the form from submitting when people press the Enter Key or the Return Key.

At the same time, I have textareas, where the user will need to be able to press the Enter / Return keys.

Comment: A good compromise might be to implement client-side validation.  If the user presses enter and validation fails, the form won't go through.  If they press enter and validation succeeds, the form will go through even if it's an accident, but at least you're leaving the default browser behavior intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and nasty hack but generally more reliable than trying to block keypresses in every field: add:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return false;" />
```

at the top of the form. The first submit in a form acts as a default button for when Enter is pressed in current browsers, so by neutering it you prevent an Enter-submission from occurring.

Then use CSS to hide and/or move the button so it can't be seen.

It isn't always a good idea to block Enter-submissions though; it's the standard way the browser is expected to work and some users really do want it.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.  I understand that messing with normal browser actions isn't a good idea, but sometimes you just have to do what the client wants...

Answer (score 0):

set a flag at the document level, submitform = false;
validate submissions against this.
change the flag in the onclick handler of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you add an onsubmit attribute to the form, then check if it was submitted using the enter key?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   validSubmit = false;
})

jQuery('myForm textarea').keypress(function(e) {
   if (e.which == 13) {
      validSubmit = true; // if the pressed key is enter, then allow submissions
   }
})

jQuery('myForm').submit(function(){
   if (!validSubmit) {
      return false;  //if submitting the form is not allowed, then cancel submission
   }
})
```

This cancels all submissions whatsoever unless the enter/return key is pressed on a textarea. If you are using a button, you need to add a function to that too.

```
jQuery('form button.validSubmit').click(function(){  //or 'form input[type="submit"]'
   validSubmission = true;
})
```